# How do I accept user input using python tkinter and enter it into browser checkout using selenium web automation?

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter, bots, webautomation

I've been trying to write an automated checkout program that will allow a user to enter all their information into a tkinter gui. Then the code will automatically enter all that information into the checkout section of a website. An example is kind of like what a sneaker bot would do. HoweverI keep running into an error whenever I run the code.

The error message states:

```
AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'Name.
```

I've done some research on how to fix it, but none of the forums specifically tackle the problem that I've been having. I've been using selenium and python to attempt to write this program.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.commom.keys import Keys

from tkinter import *

import time

root = Tk()

root.geometry("450x200")

def fetchName(Name):
    user = Name.get()
    print(user)

def Supreme():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/accessories/yws2o8zb6')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="add-remove- 
    buttons"]/input').click()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="cart"]/a[2]').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//* 
   [@id="order_billing_name"]').Name.get()

Name = Entry(root, width = 50, borderwidth = 5)
Name.pack()

b = Button(root, text = "Supreme", command = Supreme, width = 12, bg = 
'gray')
b.place(x = 175, y = 100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I haven't yet added all the required fields in a checkout section, I only added the first one in order to test the code to see what works in order to accept the user input

Comment: Why do you ask the same question [how-to-accept-user-input-using-python-tkinter-and-enter-it-into-browser-checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64196634/how-to-accept-user-input-using-python-tkinter-and-enter-it-into-browser-checkout) again?

Comment: Made an error when i asked the question

Comment: You should either update the question instead of creating new one, or remove the previous question.

Comment: Will do, do you have any idea as to how i can fix my problem?

Comment: What do you want to do on this line: `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_billing_name"]').Name.get()`? As `find_element_by_xpath()` returns a `WebElement` object which, as the error said, does not have an attribute `Name`.

Comment: I am trying to access the information that the user inputs into the tkinter window and then print it in the checkout section of this link that is pasted below. Basically in the end, the user should be able to enter all their checkout information and it should automatically enter into the websites checkout section.  If you go to this link here you will see the checkout page: https://www.supremenewyork.com/checkout

Comment: As I don't know about `XPATH` syntax, is it something like `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="order_billing_name"]/'+Name.get())` instead?

Comment: It detects the name, but it now returns a new error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="order_billing_name"]/Zia"}